# How to Print Something Every Other Time Something Happens

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python and while learning I've come across a bit of a problem.

```
import time
import pyautogui

def SendScript():
    time.sleep(2)
    with open('script.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.typewrite(line.strip())
        pyautogui.press('enter')
SendScript()
```

I'm trying to print something to the screen every second time the 'enter' key has been pressed, but I'm an extreme beginner so I really don't know how to do that. Could someone help me accomplish this task?

Comment: Do you mean you want to press the enter key twice per line? Or is it that you want to only `typewrite` once every other line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new boolean variable to track if the enter key has been pressed before. That way, every time the for loop iterates, the value of `pressed` switches and only when the value of `pressed` is True will it print something.

```
import time
import pyautogui

def SendScript():
    pressed = False
    time.sleep(2)
    with open('script.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        time.sleep(2)
        if pressed:
            print("Something")
        pressed = not pressed
        pyautogui.typewrite(line.strip())
        pyautogui.press('enter')
SendScript()
```

Comment: Instead of `pressed = False; else: pressed = True` you could also simply use `pressed = not pressed`

Comment: @salilnaik, what would I do if I wanted to print "something" before " pyautogui.typewrite(line.strip())"
for example, if  pyautogui.typewrite(line.strip()) printed "hi"
i would want it to say "something" "hi"
instead of "hi" something"

Comment: @Minute I made some changes so now it should print before `pyautogui.typewrite(line.strip())`.

Comment: ```import time
import pyautogui

def SendScript():
    pressed = True
    time.sleep(2)
    with open('script.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.typewrite(line.strip())
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        if pressed:
            pyautogui.typewrite("Something"), pyautogui.hotkey('shift', 'enter')
        pressed = not pressed
SendScript()```

its a bit messy, but after moving some stuff around, it ended up like this :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

From a more step-back approach, you could do:

```
events=['event1', 'event2', 'event3', 'event4', 'event5', 'event6', 'event7', 'event8']

counter = 0
for event in events:
    counter += 1
    if counter % 2 == 0: # ie do stuff when divisible by 2, ie when its even
        print('print what you want to be printed every second time')
    else:
        pass
```

Of course you are not looping through events like I do in this example. The point is counting the events and only doing stuff when this count is even.

Comment: Yeah, here, but in its real application, the OP's events will not be a list, so enumerate won't work there.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in another answer already, a simple toggle can be implemented with a `bool` and then code which toggles it every time something happens:

```py
thing = False
:
if happens(something):
    thing = not thing
```

This is fine for toggling between two states. A more general approach which allows for more states is to use a numeric variable and a modulo operator:

```py
times = 0
maxtimes = 12
:
if happens(something):
    times += 1
    if times % maxtimes == 1:
        print("ding dong")
```

The modulo could be compared to 0 instead if you want to print on the 12th, 24th etc iterations instead of the first, the 13th, etc, or of course any other offset within the period if that's what you want.

Another useful trick is to flip-flop between zero and some other value.

```py
value = 0
othervalue = 1234
:
if happens(something):
    value = othervalue - value
```

Of course, you can flip-flop between any two values actually; subtract the current value from their sum to get the other one.

Needless to say, *just* toggling or flip-flopping isn't very useful on its own; you'd probably add some (directly or indirectly) user-visible actions inside the `if happens(something):` block too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator for this:

```py
def everySecondTime():
    while True:
        yield "hi"
        yield "not hi"

mygen = everySecondTime()
print(next(mygen))
print(next(mygen))
print(next(mygen))
print(next(mygen))
```

This prints

```
hi
not hi
hi
not hi
```

I'm sure it's clear to you how you could adapt this to do some other actions instead.

Whether this approach is better than just using a boolean is highly debatable, but I thought I'd leave it here so you could learn about generators (the `yield` keyword) if you want to.